# Fish Shell: validate if string contains substring

Tags: string, shell, fish

Currently I'm trying to validate if my string which contains a path contains a specific string.

I've already tried the bash comparison:

1. if [ $path = *$needle* ]

and

2. if [ $path =~ $needle ]

I also try the 'contains' keyword. But i'm not sure if I'm suppose to use this with a string..

Unfortunately these attempts all failed. :/

```
function next_dir
    set foundcwd 0
    set cwd $PWD
    set error 'There is no next directory to navigate to...'

    if [ -z $cwd ]
        echo $error
    else
        echo $cwd
        for d in ../*/
            set needle (string split "/" -- $d)[2]

            if [ $foundcwd = 1 ]
                cd $d
                break
            end

            if [ $cwd =~ $needle ]
                $foundcwd = 1
            end
        end
    end
end
```

The goal of my function is to navigate to the next (sibling) directory.

/mnt/c/workingdirectory/repoA --> current directory
/mnt/c/workingdirectory/repoB --> navigate to repoB

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `string match`.

```
if string match -q  -- $needle $path
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, is it okey if i use the -e parameter? It doesn't seem to work otherwise.

Comment: The '-e' parameter means to print the entire string that included a match, not just the part that did. It is useless with '-q', which turns off printing entirely, so you must have done something else wrong. Your code would help.

Comment: if string match -q -e -- $needle $cwd
                set foundcwd 1
            end

$needle contains the name of the repo ---> "example repo name"
$cwd contains the name of the directory --> "/mnt/c/workspace/example repo name"

Comment: Aaah, okay. Yeah, `string match` defaults to glob-mode, in which case it'll require `*` for the parts that don't have to match literally - like globs for files. `-e` does indeed turn that off. It's alright.